# Wrapper cannot instantiate an abstract class

Tags: c++, wrapper

I have created the Wrapper for the class library in the C++ and when I built the wrapper I got the following error as 
`Wrapper cannot instantiate an abstract class.`

Where in the Wrapper.cpp file,

```
IWrapper *IWrapper::CreateInstance()
{
IWrapper *instance =(IWrapper *)new Wrapper();
return (instance);
}
```

I get the error mentioned above on the line:

```
IWrapper *instance = (IWrapper *)new Wrapper();
```

Please provide the solution and let me know.

Comment: An abstract class can't be instantiated.

Comment: If the question is "why is Wrapper abstract?" then show us its code

Comment: It is probable, that your `Wrapper` do not cover all abstract methods from `IWrapper`, if - as I presume - `Wrapper` is derivation from `IWrapper`.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `(IWrapper *)` cast.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your `IWrapper` class is abstract, and therefore you cannot instantiate it.

Infact, from the name 'I'Wrapper, that 'I' normally means *Interface* and Interface are by convention are just abstract classes. [Note: C++ has no formal meaning or definition of Interfaces unlike other languages though]

You probably want to inherit from IWrapper and override all the abstract functions in it:

```
class IWrapper
{
public:
    virtual int SomeFunc() = 0;
    virtual ~IWrapper(){}
};

class MyWrapper : public IWrapper
{
public:
   virtual int SomeFunc(){ return 42; }
};
```

and then in `CreateInstance`:

```
IWrapper* MyWrapper::CreateInstance()
{
   return new MyWrapper();
}
```

Comment: `Wrapper cannot instantiate an abstract class.`

Comment: `new Wrapper();` <- OP is not trying to instantiate `IWrapper`.